# I want to remove some customers associated with one brand from other brand in same column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, where-clause, window-functions

I need customers which are present in the x and y brand should be removed from a brand in the final output

```
Customer_id |brand 
   1        | a
   2        | a
   3        | a
   4        | a
   1        | x
   3        | y
   5        | z
```

Final Output should be like this -

```
Customer_id |brand

   2        | a
   4        | a
   1        | x
   3        | y
   5        | z
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where brand <> 'a' or not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.customerid = t.customerid and t1.brand <> 'a'
)
```

Altenatively, you can use window functions:

```
select
from (
    select t.*, bool_and(brand = 'a') over(partition by customerid) has_only_a
    from mytable t
) t
where brand <> 'a' or has_only_a
```